# Load a Ruby file from within the context of a Module?

Tags: ruby, module

This is *bar.rb*:

```rb
module Bar
end
```

Now, in *foo.rb*, I want to include this as a sub-module of `Foo`. I tried this

```rb
module Foo
    load './bar.rb'
end
```

But that just loads *bar.rb* as if it were in the global namespace. With the above code:

```rb
::Bar # => Bar
Foo::Bar # => NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Bar
```

I'm looking for a way to load the file from within the context of the module so that the above results are switched -- `Foo::Bar` defined but not `::Bar`. Basically, it would have results similar to if the code was like this:

```rb
module Foo
    module Bar
    end
end

::Bar # => NameError: uninitialized constant Bar
Foo::Bar # => Foo::Bar
```

Is this possible? I'm using Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, the answer is to use `eval`:

```rb
module Foo
    eval IO.read('./bar.rb'), binding
end

::Bar # => NameError: uninitialized constant Bar
Foo::Bar # => Foo::Bar
```

Just load the file as a string an evaluate in place with the local binding.